# Why ASP.NET Core templates is not creating few files and throwing error on creation?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

**This is how I created the project:**

**Step 1:**

[image]

**Step 2:**

[image]

**The error thrown is:**

[image]

The file structure displayed are:

[image]
[image]

**Here the files and information missing are:**

1. project.json.
2. global.json and folder in which it will be present.
3. .NET version is empty. I think .NET core dll is not present in NeGet folder like "ASP.NET.Core(vs 1.0.1)".

These files should be created according to many tutorials and documentations and blogs.

**Is it because of the error?**

**Why are project.json, global.json, ASP.NET.Core(vs 1.0.1) three files are missing?**

**Why the .NET Core version is empty in properties?**

**Should we create them manually or they are not necessary?**

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? VS2017 comes with the new VS Tooling, which is based on csproj files (rather than xproj + project.json in VS2015 tooling). The error above suggest you didn't installed .NET Core which you should for the tools (including scafolding) to work

Comment: @Tseng I am using visual studio 2017 RC. If I didn't install .NET Core then how come templates are shown. This version will comes with .NET Core. Could there be any possibility of deletion?

Comment: Don't confuse the tools with the runtime. The message explicitly says, it requires NETCoreApp 1.0, your lower screenshots shows 1.1 references. http://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/sdk you can get both, the 1.0.x runtimes/sdks as well as the newer 1.1.x

Comment: @Tseng Yes there was that in-compatibility between versions. I then update visual studio which downloaded core 1.1.0. NOW SURPRISINGLY there is no "src" folder and "web.config" file and also using "tag helpers" similar to "AngularJS". Its crazy lot of changes are made for each release. I think it will take little more months to make it stable.

Comment: @Tseng And I think it is also very very fast in terms of execution. Happening just in seconds. Like at-least 60% - 70% faster.

Comment: May be because lot of unnecessary packages are removed.